# Where is the data race in this simple c++ code

Tags: c++, thread-sanitizer, ubsan

Both `clang++` and `g++` sanitizers produce similar warning about data race for this simple code. Is it a false alarm? What is the problem?

Code:

```
#include <thread>
struct A
{
    void operator()()
    {
    }
};

struct B
{
    void operator()()
    {
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    // callable objects are created and moved into thread
    std::thread t1(A{});
    std::thread t2(B{});
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile flags:

```
-pthread -O0 -g -fsanitize=thread -fsanitize=undefined
```

Sanitizer output for `g++`:

```
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=80173)
  Write of size 8 at 0x7b0400000800 by thread T2:
    #0 pipe ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:1726 (libtsan.so.0+0x3ea28)
    #1 __sanitizer::IsAccessibleMemoryRange(unsigned long, unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_posix_libcdep.cpp:276 (libubsan.so.1+0x20102)
    #2 std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<B> > >::~_State_impl() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:201 (a.out+0x5191)
    #3 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc2cb)

  Previous write of size 8 at 0x7b0400000800 by thread T1:
    #0 pipe ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:1726 (libtsan.so.0+0x3ea28)
    #1 __sanitizer::IsAccessibleMemoryRange(unsigned long, unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_posix_libcdep.cpp:276 (libubsan.so.1+0x20102)
    #2 std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<A> > >::~_State_impl() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:201 (a.out+0x53a5)
    #3 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc2cb)

  Thread T2 (tid=80176, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605b8)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc398)
    #2 main a.cpp:20 (a.out+0x3396)

  Thread T1 (tid=80175, finished) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605b8)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdc398)
    #2 main a.cpp:19 (a.out+0x3383)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_posix_libcdep.cpp:276 in __sanitizer::IsAccessibleMemoryRange(unsigned long, unsigned long)
==================
ThreadSanitizer: reported 1 warnings
```

Note: This warning is given only when thread and UB sanitizers are both enabled.

Comment: It looks like g++ is complaining that two empty ranges overlap

Comment: What versions of Clang and GCC do you use?

Comment: My guess would be thread sanitizer finding errors in the instrumented code by UB sanitizer.

Comment: fyi - if you pass`-stdlib=libc++` to clang it doesn't complain.  So could be in the std library code.

Comment: clang++ version: `Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1`, and g++ version: `g++ (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0`

Comment: Note that some combinations of sanitizers are not allowed such as `-fsanitize=thread` cannot be combined with `-fsanitize=address`, or `-fsanitize=leak` (written in gcc doc). But I could not find any restriction for combining `-fsanitize=thread` and `-fsanitize=undefined`.

Comment: @Eljay adding `-std=c++17` did not change anything for both gcc and clang.

Comment: Threads not sharing any data, as well as both routines empty e.g. immutable - this code don't have any data race and cannot have any. Warning is from library you've linked over here `san_interceptors_posix.cpp:1726`

Comment: Should be easy to test if the error is caused by the empty classes overlapping: Make them not empty.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow tried it with integer members but it is same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The program is well-formed. It doesn't have any data race or other undefined behavior and it also doesn't have any race condition or unspecified behavior (except for the possibility of aborting with an uncaught exception if thread creation fails).

Thread sanitizer is simply not playing nice with the undefined behavior sanitizer. Whether they are meant to be usable together I am not sure. I have had issues like this before when combining them and so would recommend not doing that.

If they are meant to play nicely together, then this would indeed be a bug.

Comment: I made a trial on Xcode scheme setup GUI. Xcode allows you to select both Address and Undefined behavior sanitizers, or Thread and Undefined behavior sanitizers. But not Address and Thread sanitizers together. This seems to indicate that OP use case is legitimate.

Answer (score 3):

From [this repo](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual#non-instrumented-code)

> ## Non-instrumented code
>
> `ThreadSanitizer` generally requires all code to be
> compiled with `-fsanitize=thread`. If some code (e.g.
> dynamic libraries) is not compiled with the flag, it can lead to false
> positive race reports, false negative race reports and/or missed stack
> frames in reports depending on the nature of non-instrumented code. To
> not produce false positive reports `ThreadSanitizer` has to
> see all synchronization in the program, some synchronization
> operations (namely, atomic operations and thread-safe static
> initialization) are intercepted during compilation (and can only be
> intercepted during compilation). `ThreadSanitizer` stack
> trace collection also relies on compiler instrumentation (unwinding
> stack on each memory access is too expensive).

From [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual#faq:%7E:text=Q%3A%20I%20see%20what%20looks%20like%20a%20false%20report%20inside%20the%20libstdc%2B%2B%20(libc%2B%2B)%20code.)

> ## FAQ
>
> - Q: I see what looks like a false report inside the libstdc++
>   (libc++) code.
>
> This may happen in c++11 mode. One such
> case is discussed [here](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2014-February/035408.html).
> Note that `ThreadSanitizer` is not [yet](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/455) heavily
> tested on code that uses c++11 threading. The solution is be to
> rebuild libstdc++ (libc++) with `ThreadSanitizer` (this
> might be tricky, and the process changes periodically; contact us for
> details). It is also possible that libstdc++ (libc++) has a bug, we've
> seen at least [one such](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59215)
> before.